# JS: message.innerText font color and bg color

Tags: javascript, text, colors, message, background-color

I'm using message.innerText for string output in google extension.

```
var text="hello world";
message.innerText = text;
```

Question is how to make bg color and text color different?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can change the background color and text color by using the style properties of elements. see below snippet.

```js
var text="hello world";
var message = document.getElementById('message');
message.innerText = text;
message.style.backgroundColor = "RED";;
message.style.color = "white";
```

```html
<span id="message"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should review the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property of DOM nodes. That said, you are looking for `backgroundColor` and `color`:

```
message.style.backgroundColor = 'some valid color value';
message.style.color = 'some valid color value';
```

Comment: Thank you Rob Awesome, it works just the way I want! Sorry, can I change the font the same way?

Comment: No problem, and yes - message.style.fontFamily = “Arial”; for example. The link in my post should help you find the available properties you can utilize. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var message = document.getElementById("#message");
var text = "hello world";
message.innerText = text;
message.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
message.style.color = "#ffffff";
```

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#message {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Change Style</button>

<br /><br />

<div id="message">
  Hello
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var message = document.getElementById("message");
 var text = "hello world";
 message.innerText = text;
 message.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
 message.style.color = "#ffffff";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```